# UART baudrate is configurable by `screen` but not by `stty`

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, serial-port, debian-wheezy, stty

I have a USB to serial adapter, based on [CH340G](http://cdn2.boxtec.ch/pub/diverse/ch340g-datasheet.pdf) chip. It is connected to a device which periodically sends a string at 9600 baud. However, I seem to be able to receive the data regardless of how I configure the UART with `stty` (version 8.13):

```
# stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600  
# stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0     
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
kill = ^H; min = 100; time = 2;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -echo
# stdbuf -i0 -o0 cat /dev/ttyUSB0
data data data
^C
# stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
# stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0       
speed 115200 baud; line = 0;
kill = ^H; min = 100; time = 2;
-icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -echo
# stdbuf -i0 -o0 cat /dev/ttyUSB0         
data data data
^C
```

I suppose there's something wrong with `stty`, since `screen` works as expected. `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600` shows the data, while `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` produces no output.

Is there something I'm missing in the attempt to configure UART baudrate with `stty`?

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose there's something wrong with `stty` ...
>   ...
>   Is there something I'm missing in the attempt to configure UART baudrate with stty?

Yes, your test is flawed, so that you do not detect that the baudrate has been changed.

Some (possibly obscure) facts:

- A serial port could receive no data at all when the data is sent at a baudrate grossly slower relative to its configuration (e.g. sent at 9600 baud and receiving at 115200 baud).
- The **cat** command has a quirk that can cause it to not flush stdio buffers unless it encounters a line termination character.  IOW successive **cat** commands could display the same data when there has been no line termination.   The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130190/force-a-shell-script-to-fflush) alludes to this issue.

Your particular choice and sequence of shell commands work together to help lead you to your incorrect conclusion.

> # stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
>      # stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
>      # cat /dev/ttyUSB0
>      data data data
>      ^C

So you configure the serial terminal with the proper baudrate, and receive some data.

> # stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
>      # stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0
>      # cat /dev/ttyUSB0
>      data data data
>      ^C

After you reconfigure with a much faster baudrate, the serial port probably ceases to detect valid frames, and no new data is received.
When you issue another **cat** command, you see a display of the same data that was received previously (i.e. before the baudrate change).

---

## Addendum

You should be able to at least convince yourself that the **stty** command is not broken, and does change the baudrate as expected.
Either:

A. Instead of changing to a very fast baudrate (that cannot detect any framing), change to a moderate 38400 baud or a slower 4800 baud, either of which should cause reception/display of garbage characters (instead of valid data or nothing).

Or

B. Swap the order of baudrates.  Reset the systems, and use **stty** to configure the fast, invalid baudrate initially to cause either reception/display of garbage characters or nothing.
Then use **stty** to configure the proper baudrate, and begin to receive the data as expected.

Comment: Thanks, but I do have line termination (think of data being NMEA strings for example), and even if I didn't, line buffering would prevent `cat` from showing any data at all. I can't imagine what could cause `cat` to display the old data, since before I open the device there's no buffer to store that data.

Comment: I did a new test which hopefully excludes buffering issues.

Comment: Your question intrigues me because I encountered last week similar "stale data" issues while using USB-to-serial adapter and **cat** command.  Apparently I don't have a correct explanation, and have been unable to reproduce it.  But see the Addendum above.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to test a few other [UART adapters](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/32035/13327) when I get them, but you gave me an idea: I'll redo my test with an Arduino programmed to echo serial input to output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. I ran `strace` on screen, and came up with this, which works:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <asm/termbits.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("%s device speed\n\nSet speed for a serial device.\nFor instance:\n    %s /dev/ttyUSB0 75000\n", argv[0], argv[0]);                   
        return -1;
    }

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK);

    int speed = atoi(argv[2]);

    int tiocm; 
    struct termios2 tio;
    ioctl(fd, TCGETS2, &tio);
//    tio.c_cflag = CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL | B2000000;
    tio.c_cflag &= ~CBAUD | CS8 | CREAD | CLOCAL | BOTHER;
    tio.c_ispeed = speed;
    tio.c_ospeed = speed;
    tio.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    tio.c_cc[VTIME]=-1;
    int r = ioctl(fd, TCSETS2, &tio);

     printf("Set %s Baudrate to %s.\n",argv[1],argv[2]);
}
```